# How should I count the number of unique rows in a 'binary' matrix?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Suppose I have a matrix whose entries are only `0` and `1`, e.g.

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), nrow=5 )
```

with sample output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1    0
```

The matrix will have at most 20 columns, and will have many rows.

I want a function, let's call it `rowCounts`, that returns:

1. The number of times a particular row appears in the matrix, and
2. The index of the first occurrence of that row.

How might I solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building on Kevin's answer, here is a C++11 version using a slightly different approach:

```
List rowCounts_2(IntegerMatrix x) {
  int n = x.nrow() ;
  int nc = x.ncol() ;
  std::vector<int> hashes(n) ;
  for( int k=0, pow=1; k<nc; k++, pow*=2){
    IntegerMatrix::Column column = x.column(k) ;

    std::transform( column.begin(), column.end(), hashes.begin(), hashes.begin(), [=]( int v, int h ){
        return h + pow*v ;
    }) ;
  }

  using Pair = std::pair<int,int> ;
  std::unordered_map<int, Pair> map_counts ;

  for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
    Pair& p = map_counts[ hashes[i] ] ;
    if( p.first == 0){
      p.first = i+1 ; // using directly 1-based index
    }
    p.second++ ;
  }

  int nres = map_counts.size() ;
  IntegerVector idx(nres), counts(nres) ;
  auto it=map_counts.begin() ;
  for( int i=0; i<nres; i++, ++it){
    idx[i] = it->second.first ;
    counts[i] = it->second.second ;
  }

  return List::create( _["counts"] = counts, _["idx"] = idx );
}
```

The idea is to trade memory for speed. The first change is that I'm allocating and filling a `std::vector<int>` to host the hashes. Doing this allows me to traverse the input matrix column by column which is more efficient.

Once this is done, I'm training a hash map of pairs (index, counts) `std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int,int>>`. The key of the map is the hash, the value is a pair (index, count).

Then I just have to traverse the hash map and collect the results. The results don't appear in ascending order of `idx` (it is easy to do it if we really want that).

I get these results for `n=1e5` and `n=1e7`.

```
> m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 1e+05, TRUE), ncol = 10)

> microbenchmark(rowCounts(m), rowCountsR(m), rowCounts_2(m))
Unit: microseconds
           expr      min       lq    median        uq       max neval
   rowCounts(m) 1194.536 1201.273 1213.1450 1231.7295  1286.458   100
  rowCountsR(m)  575.004  933.637  962.8720  981.6015 23678.451   100
 rowCounts_2(m)  421.744  429.118  442.5095  455.2510   530.261   100

> m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 1e+07, TRUE), ncol = 10)

> microbenchmark(rowCounts(m), rowCountsR(m), rowCounts_2(m))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq   median        uq       max neval
   rowCounts(m) 97.22727 98.02716 98.56641 100.42262 102.07661   100
  rowCountsR(m) 57.44635 59.46188 69.34481  73.89541 100.43032   100
 rowCounts_2(m) 22.95741 23.38186 23.78068  24.16814  27.44125   100
```

Taking advantage of threading helps further. Below is how the time is split between 4 threads on my machine. See the code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/romainfrancois/10016972).

[image]

Here are benchmarks with the last version too:

```
> microbenchmark(rowCountsR(m), rowCounts_1(m), rowCounts_2(m), rowCounts_3(m,4))
Unit: milliseconds
              expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
     rowCountsR(m)  93.67895 127.58762 127.81847 128.03472 151.54455   100
    rowCounts_1(m) 120.47675 120.89169 121.31227 122.86422 137.86543   100
    rowCounts_2(m)  28.88102  29.68101  29.83790  29.97112  38.14453   100
 rowCounts_3(m, 4)  12.50059  12.68981  12.87712  13.10425  17.21966   100
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I'm not so sure about threading improving this further though. The whole operation takes 23ms. Wouldn't the overhead of creating/destroying threads be a bigger factor here? It'd be nice to test that.

Comment: It does make a difference, I have data. I'll put some code in a gist later.

Comment: I have updated the text here and put the code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/romainfrancois/10016972.

Answer (score 9):

We can take advantage of the structure of our matrix to count the number of unique rows in a nice way. Because the values are all `0` and `1`, we can define a 'hash' function that maps each row to a unique integer value, and then count those hashes.

The hash function we will implement is identical to the following R code:

```
hash <- function(x) sum(x * 2^(0:(length(x)-1)))
```

where `x` is an integer vector of `0`s and `1`s, representing a row of a matrix.

In my solution, because I'm using C++ and there is no associative container that maintains insertion order (in the standard library), I use both a `std::map<int, int>` to count hashes of each row, and a `std::vector<int>` to track the order in which hashes are inserted.

Because of the restriction of number of columns <= 20, we can compute the hashed values and store in an `int`, but to be safe for larger matrices one should store the hashes in a `double` (because overflow would occur with `n > 31`)

With that in mind, we can write a solution:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

inline int hash(IntegerMatrix::Row x) {
  int n = x.size();
  int hash = 0;
  for (int j=0; j < n; ++j) {
    hash += x[j] << j;
  }
  return hash;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rowCounts(IntegerMatrix x) {

  int nrow = x.nrow();

  typedef std::map<int, int> map_t;

  map_t counts;

  // keep track of insertion order with a separate vector
  std::vector<int> ordered_hashes;
  std::vector<int> insertion_order;

  ordered_hashes.reserve(nrow);
  insertion_order.reserve(nrow);

  for (int i=0; i < nrow; ++i) {
    IntegerMatrix::Row row = x(i, _);
    int hashed_row = hash(row);
    if (!counts[hashed_row]) {
      ordered_hashes.push_back(hashed_row);
      insertion_order.push_back(i);
    }
    ++counts[hashed_row];
  }

  // fill the 'counts' portion of the output
  int n = counts.size();
  IntegerVector output = no_init(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    output[i] = counts[ ordered_hashes[i] ];
  }

  // fill the 'idx' portion of the output
  IntegerVector idx  = no_init(n);
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    idx[i] = insertion_order[i] + 1; // 0 to 1-based indexing
  }

  return List::create(
    _["counts"] = output,
    _["idx"] = idx
  );

}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), nrow=5 )
rowCounts(m)
m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 1E5, TRUE), ncol=5 )
str(rowCounts(m))

## Compare it to a close-ish R solution
microbenchmark( times=5,
  rowCounts(m),
  table(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m)))
)
*/
```

Calling `sourceCpp` on this gives me:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('rowCounts.cpp')
> set.seed(123)
> m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), nrow=5 )
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1    0

> rowCounts(m)
$counts
[1] 1 2 1 1

$idx
[1] 1 2 3 5

> m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 1E5, TRUE), ncol=5 )
> str(rowCounts(m))
List of 2
 $ counts: int [1:32] 602 640 635 624 638 621 622 615 633 592 ...
 $ idx   : int [1:32] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

> microbenchmark( times=5,
+   rowCounts(m),
+   table(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m)))
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                    expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
                            rowCounts(m)  1.14732  1.150512  1.172886  1.183854  1.184235     5
 table(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m))) 22.95222 23.146423 23.607649 24.455728 24.953177     5
```

Answer (score 8):

I was curious how a pure R solution would perform:

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 1E5, TRUE), ncol=5 )

rowCountsR <- function(x) {
  ## calculate hash
  h <- m %*% matrix(2^(0:(ncol(x)-1)), ncol=1)
  i <- which(!duplicated(h))
  counts <- tabulate(h+1)
  counts[order(h[i])] <- counts
  list(counts=counts, idx=i)
}

library("rbenchmark")
benchmark(rowCounts(m), rowCountsR(m))
#            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1  rowCounts(m)          100   0.189    1.000     0.188        0          0         0
# 2 rowCountsR(m)          100   0.258    1.365     0.256        0          0         0
```

Edit: more columns, thanks @Arun for pointing this out.

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix( sample(0:1, 1e7, TRUE), ncol=10)
benchmark(rowCounts(m), rowCountsR(m), replications=100)
#           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
#1  rowCounts(m)          100  20.659    1.077    20.533    0.024          0         0
#2 rowCountsR(m)          100  19.183    1.000    15.641    3.408          0         0
```

Comment: This solution turned out to be faster when I ran with `m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 1e7L, TRUE), ncol=10L)` - 0.26 sec vs 0.185 sec

Comment: @Arun: great, thanks it for trying with more columns.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Performing the hashing as a matrix operation is a very good idea, and it also shows that just jumping to C++ doesn't guarantee you the fastest solution (although I imagine mine can still be improved)