# Finding row indices of the same patterns in an association matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have an association matrix (0-1 matrix) the rows are repeated in that.

I need to find which rows have the same pattern.

For e.g.

if my matrix is as below

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1
[5,]    1    1    0
```

then output should be

row no. 1, 2 and 3, 4 and 5 exhibit same pattern respectively.

I can do this using checking data frame. conditions. But I am sure that there is an elegant solution for this.

**EDIT**

expected result:

suppose output is a list 'a' then the Result for above e.g. should look like this:

```
> a
[[1]]
 [1] 1 2
[[2]]
[1] 3 4
[[3]]
 [1] 5
```

Comment: What is the expected result.?  Based on the input dataset, rows 1, 2 form one group, 3,4 another, and 5 the third.  Do you need to split the dataset?

Comment: @akrun, I have edited my question with the desired  output.

Comment: Try `split(1:nrow(m), apply(m, 1, paste, collapse=""))`

Comment: If your matrix is binary, you could, also, take ideas from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886040/how-should-i-count-the-number-of-unique-rows-in-a-binary-matrix) QA; `split(seq_len(nrow(m)), c(m %*% (2 ^ (0:(ncol(m) - 1)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
 indx <- do.call(paste, as.data.frame(m))
 setNames(split(seq_along(indx),factor(indx, unique(indx))), NULL)
 #[[1]]
 #[1] 1 2

 #[[2]]
 #[1] 3 4

 #[[3]]
 #[1] 5
```

#### data

```
 m <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 3L))
```