# R - count all combinations

Tags: r, count, combinations

I would like to count all combinations in a data.frame.

The data look like this

```
   9 10 11 12
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
4  1  1  1  1
5  1  1  1  1
6  0  0  0  0
7  1  0  0  1
8  1  0  0  1
9  1  1  1  1
10 1  1  1  1
```

The output I want is simply

```
comb     n 
1 1 1 1  5
0 0 0 0  3 
1 0 0 1  2
```

Do you know any simple function to do that ?

Thanks

```
dt = structure(list(`9` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `10` = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), `11` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1), `12` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("9", 
"10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: If your data is indeed binary you could avoid any database operation by mapping each row to a unique decimal number using `(as.matrix(dt) %*% 2 ^ (0:(length(dt) - 1)))[, 1L]` and continue from there with `duplcated` and `tabulate` to match your desired output. See this [QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886040/how-should-i-count-the-number-of-unique-rows-in-a-binary-matrix).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can either use `data.table` or `dplyr`.  These are very efficient.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dt)`), grouped by all the columns of 'dt' (`names(dt)`), we get the nrow (`.N`) as the 'Count'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[,list(Count=.N) ,names(dt)]
```

---

Or we can use a similar methodology using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
names(dt) <- make.names(names(dt))
dt %>%
   group_by_(.dots=names(dt)) %>%
   summarise(count= n())
```

#### Benchmarks

In case somebody wants to look at some metrics (and also to backup my claim earlier (`efficient!`)),

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 1e6*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))

akrunDT <-  function() {
  as.data.table(df1)[,list(Count=.N) ,names(df1)]
 }

akrunDplyr <- function() {
  df1 %>%
    group_by_(.dots=names(df1)) %>%
    summarise(count= n())
}

cathG <- function() {
 aggregate(cbind(n = 1:nrow(df1))~., df1, length)
  }

docendoD <- function() {
  as.data.frame(table(comb = do.call(paste, df1)))
}

deena <- function() {
   table(apply(df1, 1, paste, collapse = ","))
}
```

Here are the `microbenchmark` results

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrunDT(), akrunDplyr(), cathG(), docendoD(),  deena(),
  unit='relative', times=20L)
#   Unit: relative
#        expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq        max neval  cld
#     akrunDT()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000  1.0000000    20     a   
#  akrunDplyr()  1.512354  1.523357  1.307724  1.45907  1.365928  0.7539773    20     a   
#       cathG() 43.893946 43.592062 37.008677 42.10787 38.556726 17.9834245    20    c 
#    docendoD() 18.778534 19.843255 16.560827 18.85707 17.296812  8.2688541    20    b  
#       deena() 90.391417 89.449547 74.607662 85.16295 77.316143 34.6962954    20    d
```

Comment: thank @akrun but the `dplyr` solution does not work. I get `9 10 11 12 count 1 9 10 11 12    10`.

Comment: @giacomoV  I guess it is based on the unusual column names that start with numbers.

Comment: @giacomoV Please check the updated code.  It should work now.

Comment: btw akrun, I did upvote you, I wanted to find a base R sol but I do like really much the data.table one and am convinced it's more efficient ;-) and I do think it deserves more upvotes (didn't follow all the discussion about the votes, just saw the last comments)

Comment: the `.dots` argument in group_by is wicked! As usual, the code could be slightly shortened for the dplyr version, just using `count(.dots = ...)` instead of `group_by(...) %>% summarise(n())`

Comment: @Tjebo that is an old code when the `group_by_` was still around.  Now, the `_` is deprecated

Answer (score 11):

A base R solution with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(seq(nrow(dt))~., data=dt, FUN=length)
#  9 10 11 12 seq(nrow(dt))
#1 0  0  0  0             3
#2 1  0  0  1             2
#3 1  1  1  1             5
```

**edit**

To get colnames more conformed to your output, you can do:

```
`colnames<-`(aggregate(seq(nrow(dt))~., data=dt, FUN=length), c("c", "o", "m", "b", "n"))
#  c o m b n
#1 0 0 0 0 3
#2 1 0 0 1 2
#3 1 1 1 1 5
```

Or, shorter:

```
aggregate(cbind(n = 1:nrow(dt))~., dt, length)
#  9 10 11 12 n
#1 0  0  0  0 3
#2 1  0  0  1 2
#3 1  1  1  1 5
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try the following approach using only base R:

```
as.data.frame(table(comb = do.call(paste, dt)))
#     comb Freq
#1 0 0 0 0    3
#2 1 0 0 1    2
#3 1 1 1 1    5
```

Comment: To exactly match the desired output (count column as "n") you could slightly adjust the code to `as.data.frame(table(comb = do.call(paste, dt)), responseName = "n")`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe  that too : `table(apply(dt, 1, paste, collapse = ","))`

Answer (score 3):

Also in base R:

Use `unique.matrix` to get the list of unique combinations.

```
uncs <- unique.matrix(as.matrix(df), MARGIN = 1)
```

Then make comparisons and count:

```
cnts <- colSums(apply(uncs, 1, function(r) apply(dt, 1, function(r2) all(r == r2))))
cbind(comb = apply(uncs, 1, paste), n = cnts)
```

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr solution above could have been done easier with group_by_all()...

```
dt %>% group_by_all %>% count
```

...which as I understand has been superseded by the across() method. Adding in a bit of sorting, and you get:

```
dt %>% group_by(across()) %>% count %>% arrange(desc(n))

> dt %>% group_by(across()) %>% count %>% arrange(desc(n))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   9, 10, 11, 12 [3]
    `9`  `10`  `11`  `12`     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     5
2     0     0     0     0     3
3     1     0     0     1     2
```

Which you could cast to a matrix if you wished.